# Setting up facebook API using Visual Studio

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api

I am newbie in developing and learning to develop windows 7 phone application. I was trying to run the sample code for Graph API of facebook on https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk the compilation of facebook API was successful but when I try to run the example code given, it gives me error "Type or namespace name 'facebook ' could not be found. I have added facebook.dll in the project references

can anyone tell me the exact procedure to follow please ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Humm the dll was compiled for which type and version of .NET ? If it's a "desktop" .NET 3.5/4 project, you can't use it directly in your WP7 project.

You need to create a new Class Library Winows Phone 7 Project (Facebook.WP7 for example) and add the existing source files from Github to it. And now you can reference this project in your WP7 project.

Comment: Hi ,Well I figured out the problem. The dll which is generated after API is compiled is to be put in new solution directory, which I had not done. At least the given code prints "Mark Zuckerberg" now as it is supposed to do
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Which Facebook.dll you referenced in your project??? There is separate one for WP7 and Desktop version of the kit.